# match home page url with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match only the homepage of website www.mysite.com and any variations of it like mysite.com/?src=advert

I have come up with `^https?:\/\/[^\/]+(\/(\?.*|index\.com(\?)?)?)?$`

It matches www.mysite.com but I need it to match anything after /? as well www.mysite.com/? (and anything after question mark)

I don't want to match mysite.com/product/..

Comment: Regex maybe not the best tool for parsing the url

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for

```
^https?:\/\/(?:[^\/]+\.)?mysite\.com(?:\/(?:\?.*)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GFCs0L/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `https?:\/\/` - a `https://` or `http://` substring
- `(?:[^\/]+\.)?` - an optional sequence of 1 or more chars (as many as possible) other than `/` followed with a `.`
- `mysite\.com` - a literal `mysite.com` substring
- `(?:\/(?:\?.*)?)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\/` - a `/`
  - `(?:\?.*)?` - an optional sequence of `?` and then any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string